# How to preserve font size of plots during report generation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, report, matlab-figure, font-size

Is there a way to preserve font size in plots when using report generation?
I update the fontsize of figures to 14 before making a report but the following instructions in Matlab during reporting create a temporary snapshot with the default font size of 12.

```
figReporter = Figure("Source",figure(n),"SnapshotFormat","png");
imgPath = getSnapshotImage(figReporter,rpt);
```

Can anyone suggest how to approach this and generate reports with the updated font size in plots?
The plots below show the difference before and after the report generation. The font size reduces when checked in the report generated.

[image: After updating font size, before adding into report via generation]
[image: After adding into report, the font size reduces to the default size]

Comment: It looks like the font size is being preserved, but the figure size is being changed so _relatively_ the font size looks smaller. Note that you've also gained axis tick marks, as if you made the figure bigger. Can you try fixing the figure size too at every point of the export?

Comment: @Wolfie The figure size is the same during export, only the font size is changing.

Comment: As I say, you can see from the axis ticks changing that it's definitely not _only_ the font size which is changing, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] or we cannot reproduce the issue